# Why am I unable to Left Join two tables?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, amazon-aurora

This is the query that I have performed.

```
select *
from samples
left join ETL_freemark on samples.lab_number_code=ETL_freemark.Lab_Number;
```

Both tables have only about 1,000,000 rows in it. 'Samples' table is able to left join easily with other tables.

It is only when it is left joined to 'ETL_freemark' that is returning with the

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 30.016 sec

After increasing DBMS connection keep-alive interval/read timeout/connection timeout to 3000 seconds and making **indexes** for samples.lab_number_code and for ETL_freemark_Lab_number this error comes out instead

> Error Code: 1105. The last transaction was aborted due to Seamless Scaling. Please retry.  44.266 sec"

And these 3 queries work fine.

```
select *
from samples
```

and

```
select *
from ETL_freemark
```

and

```
select *
from samples
inner join ETL_freemark on samples.lab_number_code=ETL_freemark.lab_number
```

Using explain select results are these:

```
explain select *
        from samples
        left join ETL_freemark on samples.lab_number_code=ETL_freemark.Lab_Number;
```

```
1   SIMPLE  samples             ALL                 132440  100.00  
1   SIMPLE  ETL_freemark        ALL                 179093  100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Any ideas on why my left join is not working?

Comment: Do a `explain select *
from samples
left join
ETL_freemark
on samples.lab_number_code=ETL_freemark.Lab_Number;` and post the results here

Comment: Did you read all of https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-working-with-amazon-aurora-serverless/

Comment: I've read the article but how does it explain why I'm able to do an inner join at lightning quick speed but not a left join? I don't think it's about resources..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With error code 1105 AWS Aurora tells you, explicitly, that your problem happens because your "autoscaling" server ran short of resources, your belief to the contrary notwithstanding. What happens when you try again?

Comment: As for Block Nested Loop in your explain output, please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059084/what-does-using-join-buffer-block-nested-loop-mean-with-explain-mysql-command  Block Nested Loop queries require large quantities of RAM to be satisfied, so Aurora must scale up.